# Incompatible units 'rem' and '0'

Tags: css, sass, blazor, blazor-server-side, web-compiler

I'm using [AdminLte](https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE) as my base for styling.

I added [WebCompiler](https://github.com/failwyn/WebCompiler) so I can use `scss` files. So I created a new `scss` file and the first line is:

```
@use '../../wwwroot/AdminLte/dist/css/adminlte.css';
```

However, when I compile I get the following error:

> ```
> Error: 0.25rem and 0 are incompatible.
> ? 4884 �   border-top-left-radius: calc(0.25rem - 0);
> ```

I understand that this might be an incompatibilty issue when using 'SASS', and I obviously do not want to change the AdminLte css file.

So what are my other options to solve this problem?

Comment: why'd you want to subtract `0` specifically?

Comment: That's what in the original 3rd party code.

Comment: first of all its not a `sass` issue. And secondly I reported it in **AdminLte** [repo](https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/issues/4623)

Comment: Why not overriding the CSS ? in another file add border-top-left-radius: calc(0.25rem - 0rem)